# Unable to post visitor post to a facebook page using graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a visitor post to a facebook page using graph API(Using Koala Gem). Getting the below error,

Koala::Facebook::ClientError: type: OAuthException, code: 200, message: (#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission, x-fb-trace-id: DlkUWs8nor8 [HTTP 403]
from /Users/sengottaiann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@twitter_fix/gems/koala-3.0.0/lib/koala/api.rb:50:in `graph_call'

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: are you using a page token with the publish_pages permission?

Comment: Yes ... we are using page token with publish_pages permission ...

Comment: do you also have the 'manage_pages' permission?

Comment: You can not make a _visitor_ post using a _page_ access token. You can not post in the name of a user at all any more via API, the necessary permissions have been removed.